# DragLeave event is firing in loop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing drag and drop functionality.
I just wanted to add element to `ObservableCollection` when drag enters and mouse is over the canvas and remove from `ObservableCollection` when drag leaves the canvas.

Unfortunately `DragLeave` and `DragEnter` is firing constantly even if the cursor is over canvas and I do not move it. Why it happens?

Comment: Make sure the xaml for the dragleave and dragenter is in the right spot in your xaml, if you have it outside the observablecollection(datagrid or listbox i presume) then you will get this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201198/wpf-drag-on-canvas-with-preview Here is my xaml

Comment: I suspect you are doing something to trigger DragLeave when DragEnter fires, and vice versa. For example, if you create an object below the mouse on DragEnter, then DragLeave gets triggered because the mouse is no longer over the Canvas (it's over the newly created object instead), and DragLeave removes the object which means the mouse is over the Canvas again so DragEnter gets fired.... and the same process gets repeated endlessly unless the mouse is removed from the Canvas entirely

Comment: DragEnter is just adding an object into ObervableCollection

Comment: @latata Does the object added to the ObservableCollection get created under where the Mouse is currently located? Or does it fire something like a PropertyChange event which causes the UI to redraw?

Comment: yes. the object is created where the mouse is located (is moving with mouse position)

Comment: so how to prevent dragleaving after adding element to canvas over mouse?

Comment: When you create the object, set `IsHitTestVisible = false`, until you need to be able to click on it again.